# Questions about enabling special pool on win32k

Tags: windows, kernel, fuzzing

So there is `win32k.sys`, `win32kbase.sys`, `win32kfull.sys` in Windows 10

Does `verifier /driver win32k.sys /flags 0x1` enable special pool on all three drivers? (win32k.sys is kinda like stub to other drivers)

Because I have a crash that occurs only when enabling special pool specifically on `win32kfull.sys` by `verifier /driver win32kfull.sys /flags 0x1`. It doesn't crash when enabling special pool on `win32k.sys` or `win32kbase.sys`. Is this case weird?

Also, what would be the general setup regarding turning on the special pool when fuzzing `win32k*.sys`?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you head over to the `ntdev` mailing list (and forum) on the OSR website. Ask it there, higher chance of getting an answer and higher chance of getting it from someone working on a team that maintains these drivers. Of course you may want to cut down on the notion that you're fuzzing stuff ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just enable special pool on all 3 drivers:

```
verifier.exe /flags 0x1 /driver win32k.sys /driver win32kbase.sys /driver win32kfull.sys
```

Comment: Can you explain how this answers the question? After all the inquirer was asking _whether_ enabling special pool on `win32k.sys` _also_ affects the other two "companion" drivers. Admittedly this could be seen as addressing the secondary question crammed into the last paragraph by the inquirer.

Comment: Actually `verifier.exe /flags 0x1 /driver win32k.sys win32kbase.sys win32kfull.sys` works.

Comment: Well I guess this partially answers my question. The reason I asked is because I couldn't get all 3 drivers to have special pool turned on so was wondering whether turning it on `win32k.sys` will have similar affect. Now I got all 3 to have special pools turn on, but still the other question I must find out.

Comment: `verifier /driver win32k.sys /flags 0x1` will enable special pool only for memory allocated in `win32k.sys` code. It looks like your memory corruption is in a memory chunk allocated in `win32kfull.sys`, that's why enabling special pool on this driver alone leads to a crash, and enabling it on other drivers does not.